# How to check a row already exists before copying the data from csv to postgres using python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have tried to dump csv data from multiple files to postgres using python.I succeed in doing so.But I want to check if a particular row already exists before copying into database postgres.Please check my code

```
 SQL_STATEMENT = """
    COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH
        CSV
        HEADER
        DELIMITER AS ','
    """

def process_file(conn, table_name, file_object):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.
    cursor.copy_expert(sql=SQL_STATEMENT % table_name, file=file_object)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()


connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dataflow user=postgres host=localhost password=root")
try:
    process_file(connection, 'mytable', f)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Please suggest me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`COPY` just loads properly formatted data to a table - no preprocessing. Thus you can copy csv to temp table and then insert rows to you table skipping existing:

```
   CREATE TABLE temp_t AS SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE false
   ;
   COPY temp_t FROM STDIN WITH
        CSV
        HEADER
        DELIMITER AS ','
    ;
    INSERT INTO table_name 
      SELECT * 
      FROM temp_t
      EXCEPT
      SELECT * 
      FROM table_name
     ;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

> COPY FROM copies data from a file to a table (appending the data to
>   whatever is in the table already)

Comment: iam using just copy but the data is loading into tbale

Comment: ok.shall you edit my code and answer where  have to chnage this ....npi is one of the column that is unique

Comment: I gave you completely working SQ code - just wrap it to python as you like it.